# Test-dependent teardown fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using teardown fixtures as follow

```
@pytest.fixture
def clean_after_test()
    yield
    function_to_clean()

def test_object(clean_after_test)
    <TESTING CODE>
```

But in specific  test-case I need to create object, do something with it and after testing done remove it by ID. ID I can get only when test is in progress so I cannot use teardown fixture as usually since I cannot know ID in advance.
I can add object-removal code line at the end of test, but it will be executed only in case of passed status, so it's a bad option

So what will be the best practice for cleaning-up after test based on data received during test?

Comment: Rather than worrying bout a dedicated teardown fixture, I would recommend an implementation where whatever object generates the id is done so during setup and thus will automatically clean up after itself. Actual code is needed to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @TeejayBruno I cannot control object creation and so setting predefined ID is impossible...

Comment: How about creating the object inside the fixture?

Comment: @Tzane, hmm... that might be an option. currently, as workaround, I use `try/finally` construction, but definitelly need to stick to fixture implementation...